# Electron js: sudo access

Tags: electron, sudo

I'm trying to create an electron app (for mac and windows) that copies some file to the root directory e.g `/etc/`. This requires sudo permissions from the user

After doing some research I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt which lets electron execute sudo commands by prompting the user for access. However, I still failed to execute

```
command = "mv ~/Desktop/some-file /etc";


sudo.exec(command, {},
  function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Sudo Command Successful');
    }
  }
);
```

The output of which I'm getting:

```
Error: Command failed: mv ~/Desktop/some-file /etc
mv: rename /Users/test/Desktop/some-file to /etc/some-file: Operation not permitted

    at /Users/test/Desktop/host_test/node_modules/sudo-prompt/index.js:390:27
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read/context:68:3) {
  code: 1
}
```

When I run `sudo cp ~/Desktop/some-file /etc` from a terminal it works as expected. I would expect sudo-prompt to do the same. So I guess my question is:

Is there a better way to get sudo access in an electron app to perform some tasks?

Any insights to why sudo-prompt is not working would also be appreciated

Comment: Because such access is inherently a security risk, therefore every system has every reason to block such access, and no motivation to ever provide to you.  No app should ever be able to copy anything to the root directory, and there's no use case that is not simply someone attempting to create a security risk and escalate toward admin privledges.  All apps should always exist in a sandbox where root is never available.  If you are not sitting at a computer somewhere, you do not need root access.